# improving speed of GetPixel function in c#

Tags: c#, image, getpixel

i need to read getpixel of bmp with speed but is very low
i used of LockBits

```
     private void LockUnlockBitsExample(Bitmap bmp)
    {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    }
```

and this function

```
        private Color GetMyPixel(byte[] rgbValues,Bitmap bmp, int x,int y )
    {

        int index= (bmp.Width*y+x)*3;
        Color MyColor = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[index], rgbValues[index + 1], rgbValues[index + 2]);
        return MyColor;
    }
```

but output of my function is different from original getpixel

Comment: What is the color format of the original image? Looks like Your GetMyPixel function assume the images are 24 bits per pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have code in VB for some reason that does almost the exact same thing as you, so I hope this helps.  You can try the following modification to GetMyPixel:

Use Stride instead of Width and invert the byte order in your call to FromArgb.

```
private Color GetMyPixel(byte[] rgbValues,Bitmap bmp, int x,int y )
{
   int index= (bmp.Stride*y+x*3);        
   if (index > rgbValues.Length - 3)
   index = rgbValues.Length - 3;
   Color MyColor = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[index+2], rgbValues[index + 1], rgbValues[index]);         
    return MyColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

`int index= (bmp.Width*y+x)*3;`

I believe that `bmp.Stride` must be used instead of `bmp.Width`. Also check assumption that `PixelFormat` is 24 bits per pixel.

Another thing are color indexes: blue is first (`index`), then green (`index+1`), then red (`index + 2`).

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I want to say that simply replacing bmp.Width with bmp.Stride would be incorrect as you would not want to multiply the stride by y and by 3 (bytes per pixel).  Width is the length is pixels, so it is correct to multiply that by 3, but it is not correct to multiply the stride by 3.

Comment: @JasonHermann You are absolutely right. I had to missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this post out :[working with lockbits](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)

it helped me a lot when i did something similar